# Adding User ID to a Post with a button click in Laravel puts out an error saying "Post Method Not Supported"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, post

In this app I have a User table, and a Posts table.

In the individual post blade (post/{id}) I have a button called "Pick Up Task". When clicked, it should set $post->user to the current user's ID. I have set up everything as per the current documentation, yet it still gives me the error: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Here is my code:

Button in Post Blade

```
<form action="update" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{ $task->id }}"/>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value= "UPDATE" href="#">➕ Pick up Task</button>
                </form>
```

Function in the Post Controller

```
// ADD USER TO TASK
public function update() 
{
    $user = request('user_id');
    $task = request('task_id');

    //Fill Post User
    $selectedtask = Posts::findOrFail($task);
    $selectedtask->update(['user', $user]);

    //Success
    Session::flash('success', 'You picked up a new task.');
    return view('/');

}
```

My Routes (web.php)

```
//Add user as assignee
Route::POST('update', 'PostController@update');
```

Comment: Are you sure that your form action sends you to the correct route?

Comment: Does your route show up correctly when running `php artisan route:list`? Have you tried `Route::post(...)` instead of `Route::POST(...)`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if the form action sends me to the correct route (it does as far as I can tell). And the route does show up correctly when I do `route:list` - it shows `POST | update | PostController@update | web, auth`. Lowercase presents me with the same issue.

Comment: @Repox how could I validate whether the form action is sending me to the correct route?

Comment: @cslem Well, what route is it actually posting to, when you press the submit button (what URL does it produce)? You route currently suggest that you would be submitting to `http://example.com/update`, but when you're pressing submit, is that the URL your sending to?

Comment: @Repox it's sending me to `https://example.com/post/update` from `https://example.com/post/{id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try move

```
Route::POST('update', 'PostController@update');
```

to top of web.php file, then clear route cache, change code

```
<form action="/update" method="POST">
```

(add slash before update) and try your code

Comment: try move Route::POST('update', 'PostController@update'); to top of web.php file, then clear route cache, change code <form action="/update" method="POST"> (add slash before update) and try your code

Comment: That did something! I now get the error ` Add [0] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Posts]. `

Comment: Show me your Post model, maybe you don't set fillable array

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning so much, I really appreciate it. Here is my post model:

`class Posts extends Model
{
    //Table Associated with the Model
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');
    }

}`

Comment: If you have column user in posts table, you need in Post model add property protected $fillable = ['user'];

Answer (score 1):

You're being sent to the wrong URI.

Change your `form` tag to this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

This will ensure that you are being sent to the exact same route you're currently on, but with a POST method instead of the GET method.

Your routes should look like this:

```
Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostController@show'); // For viewing
Route::post('post/{post}', 'PostController@update'); // For updating
```

Correct your `update` controller method to work with the parameters via [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding):

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post) 
{
    $user = request('user_id');
    $task = request('task_id');

    //Fill Post User
    $selectedtask = Posts::findOrFail($task);
    $selectedtask->update(['user', $user]);

    //Success
    Session::flash('success', 'You picked up a new task.');
    return view('/');

}
```

I'm also assuming that you're mixing up `task_id` with the ID of a Post model, since you're fetching a post via that request variable? You can, by using model binding and accessing the user via the Request object, boil down your controller method to the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post) 
{
    $post->update(['user' => $request->user()->id]);
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'You picked up a new task.');
}
```

Model binding will automatically return a 404 if the doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, thank you - I got it working as per the advice below, but I would definitely like to try and refactor my code as you've listed above. Some questions. 

How would my new route for 'update' look if the view route is currently `Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostController@view')->name('task');`

I know i've got bad naming conventions (switching between post and task), but task_id is pulling the same {id} that I'm viewing in the route above. Would that change anything here?